# How to find textbox value in this table layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I want to get the value of textbox in `colB` when the button is clicked on the same row.
However, my selectors are not getting there. Also, it has to work in IE8.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvdDm/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>colA</th>
            <th>colB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <a class=btn class=foo>foo</a>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text value=1 />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text value=2 />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a class=btn class=foo>foo</a>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text value=3 />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type=text value=4 />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


$('.foo').on('click', function (item, evt) {
    var foo = $(evt.target);
    var tr = btn.parent().parent();
    var col3 = tr.children(':eq(2)');
    var txt = col3.find('input');
    alert(txt.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function () {
    var btn = $(this),
        tr = btn.closest('tr'),
        col3 = tr.find('td').eq(2),
        txt = col3.find('input');

    alert(txt.val());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LvdDm/5/).

Note that this requires some corrected HTML:

```
<td>
    <a class='btn foo'>foo</a>    
</td>
```

You had an multiple `class` attributes (you can only have one), each with a single (unquoted) class-name (which is valid, quotes *are* optional but *only* if there's only *one* value).

Also, you were using:

```
var foo = $(evt.target);
```

Within the `on()` method it *seems* that there is no iterator (which makes sense, since it can only act on one element at a time), so the event-object was where you had `item`, and there was no `evt` being passed, so the selector was a `null` object.

And with the following:

```
var tr = btn.parent().parent();
```

You never defined the `btn` variable, so it couldn't be used to find the ancestor(s).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: the sample code was typed in a rush. Since I'm using the click in KO.js, so I used `evt.currentTarget` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this using the jQuery code, why don't you assign an id to the buttons that is related to the row. When it is clicked, grab the textbox value of that respective column, would make it so much simpler. Also, the way you assign classes and types aren't correct. They need to be enclosed in quotation marks. Multiple classes also do not require multiple class attributes, so the button class should be class="btn foo", not class="btn" class="foo".

example:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> <a id="col1" class="btn foo">foo</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="col1_input1" type="text" value=1 />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="col1_input2" type="text" value=2 />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

etc